# Laravel Request not found when called within a Controller's function

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5

I am trying to authorise the user to submit a post request, by using a `Request` within Laravel. The error I am getting is:

> ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 57: Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\UpdateClinicDescriptionFormRequest does not exist

It's as if Laravel is trying to look within Controllers for the Request, but it's clearly in the Request's folder.

The `UpdateClinicDescriptionFormRequest.php` file is in the Request's folder.

The function trying to access to Request is:

```
 public function postUpdateDescription(UpdateClinicDescriptionFormRequest $request, $id)
 {
    $clinic = Clinic::find($id);

    $clinic->description = Input::get('description');
    $clinic->save();
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you haven't imported it. Add this at the top of your controller, after the namespace declaration:

```
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateClinicDescriptionFormRequest;
```

And make sure that file is properly namespaced:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
```

Comment: I triple checked everything on the Request, apart from importing it. A second pair of eyes! Thank you Joel.